# Adding Retrofit 2 To Gradle Give Failed to Resolve

Tags: android, retrofit2

I try to add

`compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3'`

then sync gradle. Unfortunately it's failed :

> Failed to resolve: com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3

Below my repo in build.gradle :

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com"
    }
}
```

Comment: what repo are you using?

Comment: @njzk2 i added repo info in my question

Comment: you need either jcenter or mavenCentral as repo

Comment: @njk2 unfortunately still not work. Already tried to add jcenter() and mavenCentral either in app/build.gradle or ~/build.gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to solve my own problem for more than 12 hours and finally i got the solution.

I open gradle.properties and found there is network proxy setting in that file. The network proxy setting is in that file because i pull the source code from git which the original source code has network proxy configuration in gradle.properties file :((

I delete the network proxy configuration and problem is solved.

Conclusion :
To fix

> Failed to resolve: com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3

First make sure network configuration in computer or gradle.properties is correct

Answer (score -2):

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com"
    }
}
```

Comment: not working. Already tried to add jcenter() and mavenCentral either in app/build.gradle or ~/build.gradle